# Call a zero-initialized variable of internal function type

Tags: solidity, exceptions, assert

I was reading [solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/control-structures.html#error-handling-assert-require-revert-and-exceptions) about when an assert-style exception is generated. In the 6th point it says:

"If you call a zero-initialized variable of internal function type."

I don't understand it. Can someone give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables can contain function pointers. If you leave them uninitialized and then try to call them, the call will fail because the variable was zero-initialized and therefore it does not contain a pointer to a callable function. Example:

```
function b(int x, int y) internal pure returns (int)
{
    return x * y;
}

function test1() external pure returns (int)
{
    // Variable containing a function pointer
    function (int, int) internal pure returns (int) funcPtr;

    funcPtr = b;

    // This call to funcPtr will succeed
    return funcPtr(4, 5);
}

function test2() external pure returns (int)
{
    // Variable containing a function pointer
    function (int, int) internal pure returns (int) funcPtr;

    // This call will fail because funcPtr is still a zero-initialized function pointer
    return funcPtr(4, 5);
}
```